# Dynamic component in one template with react

Tags: templates, dynamic, reactjs

For example with ad in bbs,

[image]

In above picture,

there are many shapes of template but same url level

How can I implement this??

I think I could code with hard coding some degree, but if bbs category is over ~ 1000 or over 10000, I will die soon.

Do I have to create over 10000 category folder with different template??
or
Do I have to create query method over 10000 with each category??

How can I manage this use case?? What is best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-router` library to handle query string parameters. Read [this tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params) about `react-router`.

For example you can read parameter value and fetch proper data from server.

Comment: I'm using react-router, I can get bbs Id but how can I make and manage different bbs head template?? I think so many `if (bbs.id)` is needed

Comment: @user3449782: You just need to read bbs id and using an API to request data or request a page with same name (for example `bbs-page-1.html`).

Comment: So, you mean I need each page with each API?? so with 1000 bbs, 1000 bbs head htmls and each specific API?

Comment: @user3449782: No I didn't mean that. For example you have an API like `mydomain.com/bbs/:id` and send proper id for every page.

Comment: @user3449782: Yeah, for example read proper bbs from your database and send it as json.